# How can i use port forwarding to multi ip

Tags: iptables, ip, ssh-tunnel

I have two IPs (public IPs) **eth0**: `1.1.1.1` and **eth0:1**: `2.2.2.2`

I'm using portforwarding.

```
ssh -D 1080 root@2.2.2.2
```

But when i go to check ip site (ip2location) then my ip is: `1.1.1.1`

I want to use: `ssh -D 1081 root@1.1.1.1` --> shown on external site as my ip `1.1.1.1`

And `ssh -D 1080 root@2.2.2.2` --> view on external site as my ip  `2.2.2.2`

Please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

This is more difficult than your question implies.

Using SSH SOCKS proxy, the server sshd process will establish the connections on your client's behalf. The selection of the source IP pays no attention to the port or IP that you connected to and there are no arguments to `ssh` you can give to explicitly set one.

[The source IP of the connection is chosen](http://linux-ip.net/html/routing-saddr-selection.html) by (in order):

- any explicit one set by the application (the ssh client doesn't allow
  for this)
- the `src` *hint* in the route table (not set by default)
- the first configured IP on the interface (usually the default
  option and probably why all your connections through the proxy come *from* 1.1.1.1.

A crude way to solve this is, on connection, use some script-fu to ascertain the port or IP used for your ssh connection and to run the relevant `ip route add default via <next-hop> src 1.1.1.1` command to set the *hint*, but that will only work if you have only one proxy connection open at a time; the command will change the default source IP for all connections from the server.

A cleaner way might be to use iproute2's [policy-based routing](http://baturin.org/docs/iproute2/#Policy-based%20routing). Configure two separate route tables, each with the relevant `src` hint, and then perhaps create a policy that selects one table based on the user context, thereby routing with the appropriate source IP.

Comment: Can you tell me step by step?

Comment: Sorry, I doubt anyone has time to come up with a full solution as it would take some back and forth and debugging to get right. Also, you didn't mention your platform and I've assumed Linux. The links I've provided should give you a head start and some terms to Google for. There's a whole book here: http://www.lartc.org/lartc.html and another guide, here: http://www.policyrouting.org/iproute2.doc.html. Good luck!